# How to disable a button after clicking it eventhough user refreshes the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed a HTML 5 + JavaScript mobile webpage. In my page i have a button called "submit". When i clicked it-button value will changed to "Done".
But if i refresh my page after clicking "submit" button, the default value for button("submit") appears.

What i need is once i clicked that button,it's value should be only "done" even though user refreshes his page.
Is there any specific method to do this?

```
<style>
.selectBtn{height:60px;width:80px;
background-color:yellow;}
#abc{background-color:gray;height:100%;width:60%;}
</style>
</head>
<body><div id='abc'></div>
<script>
content = document.getElementById('abc');
function dx(){
var Btn = document.createElement('button');
Btn.type = 'button';Btn.className = 'selectBtn';
Btn.innerHTML = 'Submit';
Btn.onclick = function()
{
this.innerHTML='Done';
}
content.appendChild(Btn);   
}
dx();
</script>
```

Comment: You can't get this done with only client side code. You can do something similar with localStorage, but that works until the user clears it on the client side.

Comment: go and google localStorage.getItem or localStorage.setItem :) this could be a idea to safe the actually state of the button.

Comment: How long should the button have the label `Done`? What should happen if the user closes the window and reopens the page?

Comment: cookie is another bad option :)

Comment: t.niese : It should be disabled until user exits the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store information about if button is clicked, in a cookie. You can set and read this cookie with javascript and disable button if cookie exists or has particular value. 
This is easy-cheatable, user can delete or modify cookies. If you need it to be more reliable, you need to store it on server side.

Comment: Storing server side also needs a cookie. Deleting the cookie means loosing the information about the user/session. So it is not really more reliable.

Comment: @t.niese Well, you can store user-agent and/or user ip, than you do not necessary need cookie. But I must agree it is still cheatable, unless fully functional login (user sessions) system is implemented.

Comment: Thanks guys. Then i'll try to store it in server side.

Comment: Well an IP could change (e.g. when using mobile devices that could have a different IP if there is a switch to a different cell). Or an IP could also be shared in companies (where the User-Agent will be also the same if it is a central managed setup). Anyway cookie and server side storage is definitely a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Use one hiddenfield and set value to true once button clicked and when user refreshes pageload fires there if the value is set to true change button name to done

```
Btn.onclick = function()
{
  this.innerHTML='Done';
  var hdnvalue=document.getElementById("hiddenfield1");
  hdnvalue.value="true";
 }

function pageload()
{
   var hdnvalue=document.getElementById("hiddenfield1");
  if(hdnvalue=="true")
  {
    Btn.innerHTML='Done';
  }
}
```

Comment: Well on reload the hidden field will also have it's default value again. Some browser keep the stat of input fields (I don't know if this is also true for hidden fields) upon reload but not every.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage to store the value of the button and load it when the user restarts the webpage.

```
btn.innerHTML=localStorage.btn_value


Btn.onclick = function()
{
this.innerHTML='Done';
localStorage.btn_value=this.innerHTML;
}
```

This should work...

Comment: will buttons created thro' DOM support localstorage?

Comment: @jmj `localStorage` _is_ the more powerful `cookie`. You could check this for more informations: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @jmj localStorage is a simple store, it doesn't care about DOM. And the Button code uses localStorage on its own.

Comment: @t.niese I was about to say that the down-side of this is HTML5-only :)

Comment: localStorage is just a storage like @zladuric said. Since you are talking about HTML5, I suppose, the browser you are working with will have high chance of supporting localstorage.

Comment: @zladuric yes i removed that right at the moment you wrote :D

Answer (score 0):

You could work out a (semi-)HTML5 way for this.

When you click the button, also alter the URL has. And you can then set the value of the button to "done" on the server. Or your server-side code can ignore this and you use JS to fix it.

Pure javascript solution here:
First - change the hash on submit..

```
Btn.onclick = function () {
  // do Ajaxy submit here
  MyFramework.Ajax.submit();
  // now alter the hash
  // also, you could also move this in the ajax callback function 
  // - to make sure the submit worked.
  window.location.hash = 'done';
}
```

Now, this part is, let's call it, button init - it checks for the value of hash. Let's say you initialize your button with Javascript.

```
Button.init = function { // or onPageLoad or whatever
  if('#done' == window.location.hash) {
    Button.setLabel('Done'); // or variation thereof
  }
};
```

Edit: Just saw you already have init function: *dx*, so alter the line `Btn.innerHTML = 'Submit';` to
`if('#done' == window.location.hash) {
  Btn.innerHTML = 'Done';
} else {
  Btn.innerHTML = 'Submit';
}`

Of course, if you already do use hash, you need to include an if or two :)

Answer (score 0):

How about session storage? The button will show "done" until the user closes the window or tab

```
<style>
.selectBtn{height:60px;width:80px;
  background-color:yellow;}
#abc{background-color:gray;height:100%;width:60%;}
</style>
</head>
<body><div id='abc'></div>
<script>
content = document.getElementById('abc');

function dx(){
  var Btn = document.createElement('button');
  Btn.type = 'button';
  Btn.className = 'selectBtn';
  Btn.innerHTML = 'Submit';
  Btn.onclick = function() {
    this.innerHTML='Done';
    sessionStorage.done = true;
  }
  if (sessionStorage.done) {
    Btn.innerHTML = 'Done';
  }
  content.appendChild(Btn);   
}

dx();
</script>
```